# How to find the file which was last updated on my Linux box?

Tags: linux, find

I'm executing a command which updates a file in an unknown location on my system. What is the the `find`/`locace`/whatever command that will tell me, which file was the last to update on the system? This command needs to know not to look in `proc` or any other locations which are not relevant.

Comment: If you can run the command again, run `strace -o log.txt thecommand`. The log file will show all system calls, including those that will help identify all the files created or written to by the command.  Look for `open` and `write` system calls in the log. You may also have to look at `chdir` and `mmap` calls to be thorough.

Comment: Actually this is a great idea. Not a s clean as I wanted but will definitely do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Is this any help for you?

```
find / -mtime -5 | head -1
```

This tells you which files were changed in last 5 minutes and outputs the first line..

You can of course specify it to look only for png files for example:

```
find / -name "*.png" -mtime -5 | head -1
```

Where `/` is the directory where the search starts - in this case system root, `-name "*.png"` is a filter for your search, `-mtime -5` is a filter used to select only files modified in last 5 minutes and `| head -1` takes the output of everything before the pipe and prints just the first line.

Take in mind that without the first filter it also checks directories, so the use of the filename filter is advised.

[mtime reference](http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=20526)

Edit: If you want to exclude some folders it would probably better to write a bash script which has N folders specified for searching and then does the command for each of them.

That means your script would execute:

```
find /your/first/folder -name "*.png" -mtime -5 | head -1
```

then

```
find /your/second/folder/location -name "*.png" -mtime -5 | head -1
```

and so on..

Comment: But this will look in many places which are not relevant like `/proc`, `/boot` and so on, I'm interested in find command which can locate configuration files and let me know which one was last updated

Comment: well if you know where they are located, then just use `find {location} -mtime -5` where {location} is the path to your directory or even specify a filename filter.. or you can search only your home directory with `find ~/ -name "*.png" -mtime -5 | head -1` for example

Comment: in other words: you can't find something somewhere if you're not looking in that place - either specify where to look or search everything

Comment: Well, your answer was useful in a way, I had to filter out the results which didn't match configuration files location to find what I was looking for, something like `sudo find / -mtime -5 | grep -v ^/proc/ | grep -v ^/dev/ | grep -v ^/run/ | grep -v ^/sys/ | grep -v ^/var/ | grep -v ^/usr/`. As you can see, it's not too pretty, any other suggestions to automate this process?

Comment: As I mentioned: Write a script which only uses the folders which are relevant a searches in each of them.. Unfortunately nothing else comes to my mind at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

you could see which files are *currently* being changed with `inotifywait` command.

`inotifywait -rme modify /folder/to/monitor/`

this will list all files and directories modified in `/folder/to/monitor/` and all its subdis.

`-r` : recursive

`-m` : monitor file system until killed by user

`-e` : specify event types to monitor

and you can also tell the command to ignore some directories

`inotifywait --exclude '^/proc/' -rme modify /`

**Be aware** that setting such monitoring on the **whole file system** will take quite some time to set up and you may also have to increase the `user_watches` limit (8k by default).

> Please increase the amount of inotify watches allowed per user via `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches'

This command may be more appropriate when using on specific locations.

Comment: Indeed, interesting command which I wasn't aware of, but my main problem is that I must look under root directory since I can't know for sure where is the configuration file which I'm looking for so I can't make any assumptions about the directory which contains it.